# Kubernetes - "convert" docker-compose yaml "command" segment into k8s command and args

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, containers, azure-aks

I have in docker-compose YAML the following command segment:

```
  command:
  - /opt/sbin/demo_start
  - demo_start
  - '-unicode'
  - '-db_server test01'
```

I now need to convert that into YAML format for K8S, but I am really not sure how this should be done.

```
command: ["/opt/sbin/demo_start"]
args: ["demo_start", "-unicode","-db_server test01"]
```

p.s.- unfortunately I cannot test it, I need to deliver the prepared YAML to my admin with permissions, but I am really not sure if the above is correct.
Thanks

Comment: That seems fine; is there a specific problem you're having?  (NB: Kubernetes `command:` is Compose `entrypoint:`, and Kubernetes `args:` is Compose `command:`.)

Comment: There is no problem with your example, take a look at it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/).

Comment: Hi David and Charles, please sorry - one correction, since ENTRYPOINT in Compose file is actually defined like this: `ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/sbin/demo_start", "demo_start" ]`
that means that my K8S command should be:
`command: ["/opt/sbin/demo_start","demo_start"]`
Please confirm me if that is the case. Args will be the same without that "demo_start"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /opt/sbin/demo_start
    - demo_start
    - -unicode
    - -db_server test01
```

Comment: You can use command instead of args i just fine.

Comment: thanks for the response but my arguments are being ignored for some reason...
`command:
          - /opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start
          - ads
          - db_server vwmazfassql01`

I also tried like this, arguments are ignored as well:

        `command: ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start","ads"]
        args:
          - unicode
          - db_server vwmazfassql01`

do you know maybe what can be the issue? Thanks

Comment: Better create a new question with all the needed details so we can help you.